# command_not_found_handle: task stopped if i try to read after subshell being executed

Tags: bash

I can't understand why after attempt to call read after subshell my script stops, but works ok without susbshell call before read

```
command_not_found_handle()
{
    (true) # subshell call
    read line
    echo "$line"
}

bash-4.4$ foo

[1]+  Stopped                 foo
```

And without subshell call it works fine:

```
command_not_found_handle()
{
    read line
    echo "$line"
}

bash-4.4$ foo
smth
smth
bash-4.4$
```

Upd. Fixed in bash 5.0

Comment: You might want to update your question to make it clear that `command_not_found_handle () { try_read; }` doesn't trigger the problem. Exactly how `command_not_found_handle` is executed isn't documented in much detail, so this might simply be a bug in how the shell manages the job.

Comment: It's probably worth filing a bug report with the `bashbug` command. The maintainer can explain why this should expected or figure out what to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @chepner said this appears to be a bug. They pointed out in a since-deleted answer that running `fg` allows the command to continue, which suggests Bash thinks `command_not_found_handle` is not connected to stdin.

Adding some debugging statements demonstrates that we get past the subshell but some state about the subshell leaks into the `command_not_found_handle` environment, causing Bash to think stdin isn't available to `read` when it clearly is.

```
subshell() {
  echo "Start subshell"; (echo "In sub-shell"); echo "End subshell"
}

try_read() {
  printf "Start try_read\nInput: "; read line; echo "End try_read $line"
}

command_not_found_handle() {
  echo "Start CNFH $*"; subshell; try_read; echo "End CNFH"
}
```

This causes us to hang at `read`, after `subshell` has finished, until we `fg` the stopped job:

```
$ foo
Start CNFH foo
Start subshell
In sub-shell
End subshell
Start try_read
Input:
[1]+  Stopped                 foo

$ fg
foo
bar
End try_read bar
End CNFH
```

Removing the `subshell` call allows `read` to make progress as expected:

```
$ command_not_found_handle() { echo "Start CNFH $*"; try_read; echo "End CNFH"; }
$ foo
Start CNFH foo
Start try_read
Input: bar
End try_read bar
End CNFH
```